# How to display nested field mongodb in EJS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ejs

I am trying to display a field that contains a image link and that is nested in my collection in MongoDB to ejs. However when i try to display it EJS can't find the image.. I am using the User schema so when I write: <%=user.slot1img%> then it won't be able to find that resource.

The structure is like this for each item:

```js
Inventory: [
{
Item1: [
{
slot1img: "",
slot1text: "",
}   
],
```

So how could I show a item if its nested in mongodb to the EJS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use nested for loop

```
inventory.forEach(i => {
    i.Item1.forEach(j => {
       <%= j.slot1.img %>
    })
})
```